# Perl spawning a perl job with array on parameter

Tags: perl, spawn

I spawn a perl job with Proc::Simple, but how to pass a perl array in parameters in order to be read by the spawned process ?
My array contains JSON data so no possibility to translate into plain-text file for input to my spawned process.

To be precise :

- I've hundreds of Dell computers to check once an hour
- I got the list with a restapi against a supervisor (OME)
- JSON data returned (containing many useful information for me) is put in an array (one array line by computer) with a `@DEVS = @{$DECODED_JSON->{'value'}};`
- after that, I check every computer (looping on my array @DEVS) with a restapi against the redfish server running on it

Due to the slowness of these queries on some computers, I want to split my array by *n* and launch *n* jobs (redfish query) at the same time and wait for both ending.

Comment: How do you "_spawn a perl job with Proc::Simple_"  --  did you look at module's documentation?  One passes parameters as `$status = $proc->start(\&subname, $p1, $p2, ...);`). As for data, JSON is a string.  The whole JSON structure is a string.  I don't know how you have that in an array?  If you do have a complex data structure (and not  a JSON string) then you'd need to "serialize" it in some way.  Show some code please...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want [Minion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Minion), or any other sort of job queue. Your "workers" can grab jobs in a certain state, update those jobs to another state, and control how many thing go on at the same time. You could even retry failed jobs. This is ideal for slow things such as waiting for other systems to respond.

As for your stated problem, JSON is just data. There's nothing magical about it compared to any other string. Since we don't see any code, it's difficult to see what we could do to improve what you are doing.

Comment: I've no problem in running jobs with proc::simple, I just want to run a perl job which can accept an array as a parameter.
So, after some reflexion, 'zdim' was right : my problem is a "serialization" problem. I'll investigate further.